# django file uploads file not showing in model

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have a foreign key to a photo model, which just has photos.

Admin lists the photos as "Photo object", not the filename of the photo.

I tried with a few tips from stackoverflow to display the filename, but no luck.

How do i display the filename in admin?

Here's my model.py:

```
class Photo(models.Model):
    photo = models.FileField(upload_to='uploads/%Y/%m/%d',null=True)

    def     filename(self):
        return os.path.basename(self.file.name)

    def clean(self):
        return os.path.basename(self.file.name)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two ways:

First, in the Photo model, create '**__*unicode*__**' method

```
class Photo(models.Model):
    photo = models.FileField(upload_to='uploads/%Y/%m/%d',null=True)

    def filename(self):
        return os.path.basename(self.file.name)

    def clean(self):
        return os.path.basename(self.file.name)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.filename()
```

Two:
in admin model (See the Django docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display))

```
#In admin.py

from django import admin

class PhotoAdmin(admin.AdminModel):
    list_display("id", "filename")

    def filename(self, obj): # 'obj' represents a Photo instance
        return obj.filename()

admin.site.register(Photo, PhotoAdmin)
```